# Azure Functions Proxies - how can i strip headers sent to backend services?

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure function proxy like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "myProxy": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [
          "GET"
        ],
        "route": "/v1/something"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://myblobs.blob.core.windows.net/myfile.xml?sv={mysastoken}"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically i'm serving a file from blob storage.

Now - since this is a proxy, all request headers are passed to the `backendUri` by default.

My client (e.g browser) has an `Authorization` header from the same domain that is hosting this proxy.

When i call my proxy, i get this error (from blob storage):

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidAuthenticationInfo</Code>
<Message>
Authentication information is not given in the correct format. Check the value of Authorization header. RequestId:252247f8-f01e-0003-2673-43ed50000000 Time:2019-07-26T05:28:55.6566882Z
</Message>
</Error>
```

I assume this is because of the `Authorization` header being proxied through, as if i take it out, it works.

My question is - how can i strip this header out, when proxying through to the backend?

I've tried this:

```
"requestOverrides": {
        "backend.request.headers.Authorization": ""
      }
```

But it still errors, because the header is still being passed - just with "". I need to not send it.

Is there a way to not send this header at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you remove Authorization header, won't the client require it again ? How will the request get passed through then ?

Comment: @HariHari not sure what you mean? This proxy isn't responsible for the authorization header - it's another site on a different subdomain.

Comment: There is an open request for this: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/37353157-add-proxy-header-removal-option